# Getting global handler to all AJAX calls in dojo

Tags: ajax, dojo

I need to invoke some common methods before an AJAX call is made and after the AJAX call (before the actual handler method is called) is success. I'm using `dojo.aspect` to achieve this.

This is my code sample

```
function makeAjaxCall(){
    dojo.xhrGet({
        url:"sample_url",
        content:{
            test:"value"
        },
        load:function(response){
            //Do some logic here
        },
        error:function(response){
            //handle error
        }
    });

}
```

Below is the `dojo.aspect` which I'm using to get a hook to the `XHR` calls.

```
define(["dojo/aspect"], function(aspect){
     aspect.after(dojo, "xhr", function(deferred){
        console.log("AJAX AFTER");
        deferred.then(function(response){
            //CALLED AFTER 'load' METHOD IS CALLED.
            console.log("Testing");
        });
     });
    aspect.before(dojo, "xhr", function(method, args){

        console.log("AJAX BEFORE");
    });
});
```

Now the problem is `deferred.then` inside `aspect.after` is called after the "`load`" function is called. Is it possible to have a method which is called before the actual load method is invoked?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes.

First, there are two ways to make ajax calls in Dojo.

1. `dojo/xhr` - this is what you have above and this is deprecated
   in favor of
2. `dojo/request/xhr`

The first implementation will call into the second implementation.  So I would recommend using aop on `dojo/request/xhr`.

```
aspect.around(require.modules['dojo/request/xhr'], 'result', function(originalXhr){
    return function(url, options, returnDeferred){

        var dfd = new Deferred();

        // Logic before making the xhr call

        originalXhr(url, options, returnDeferred)
            .then(function(response) {

                // Logic handling the response but before resolving the deferred.
                dfd.resolve(vm);
                // Logic after resolving the deferred.

            }, function(err){
                // error handling?
                dfd.reject(msgs);

            }, function(update) {
                dfd.progress(update);
        });

        return dfd;
    };
});
```

You can find the complete implementation at
https://github.com/cswing/evinceframework/blob/master/evf-web-js/src/dojo/evf/serviceRegistry.js (~ line 111)

USAGE:

```
require('dojo/xhr/request', function(xhr){
    xhr({...}).then(
        function(response) {
            //handle response
        },
        function(error) {
            //handle error
        }
    );
});
```

The `dojo/xhr` code will translate itself to the usage above, so the code you posted should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to the new API - [dojo/request](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request.html)

Then you could use [dojo/request/xhr](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html) and [dojo/request/notify](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/notify.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Dojo 1.10 there is new API to globally catch state of requests.

```
notify("error", function(error){
    console.error(error);
    //SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0(…)
});
```

But in my case I get errors in html eg. so in error I get "error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0(…)"

In previous version there was an access to response object:

```
topic.subscribe("/dojo/io/error", function(/*dojo.Deferred*/ dfd, /*Object*/ response){   
  if (response.status === 401) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
```

});

So I figured out that json handler can be customized:

```
require(["dojo/request/handlers"], function(handlers){

handlers.register("json", function(response){

    if (response.status === 401) {
        window.location.reload();
        return;
    }

    return JSON.parse(response.text || null);
});
```

});

This way you are able to detect response.errors before JSON.parse throws exception.