# Catching Javascript Errors inside an AJAX onSuccess Handle with dojo

Tags: javascript, ajax, error-handling, dojo

im currently developing a WebApp with the help of dojo.

When I have an error inside my code which is executed inside the onSuccess-function of an AJAX request. (see code)

```
var promise = dojo.request.get("url");

promise.then(function(data){
    //CODE with an Error
    var test = tasd.gat().yxc;  //e.g. Reference error
  }, 

  function(err){

  });
```

This error is automatically handled by dojo (the same for e.g. prototype ajax features) and not even printed out to the console.

How can I prevent dojo from handling these errors?

I could wrap every onSuccess-function with a try catch block and handle it by myself (that worked for me), but I have many ajax calls and I don't want to do it for every call/onSuccess-function.

Im currently using the window.onError function which is very comfortable for debugging (I know it is not supported by every browser). Im using my own error handling, which also writes errors to the server, so the best solution would be to pass an error handling function to dojo for that special kind of errors or prevent dojo from setting the error as handled after it is handled by dojo to pass it on to the next handler.

Any idea how?

Thanks in advance

Moritz

p.s.: any idea how to catch all errors on the highest lvl (maybe something similar to window.onError) which works in the most browser or a library which takes care of all different browsers window.onError equivalents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to play with the AOP support in 1.9, but in the past I would use Dojo's aspect oriented support to essentially take your XHR calls and wrap them with a generic error handler.

Something like:

[Getting global handler to all AJAX calls in dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141459/getting-global-handler-to-all-ajax-calls-in-dojo)